# Azure ad access token validation in web api fails on only one server/stage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, access-token

I have crated an application to check token validity.
This app is an web api, which only holds one controller with one endpoint.
The controller is decorated with the [Authorize] attribute.
If have added a partial Startup.cs which calls the configure on app start up:

```
    public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

Also I have created a Startup.Auth.cs which handles the configuration:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
            Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"], 
ValidIssuer = Configuration Manager. AppSettings["ida:Issuer"] 
        }, 
Metadata Adress = Configuration Manager. AppSettings["ida:MetaData"] );
}
```

All I do in frontend is to call the endpoint and send an access token with a valid audience at the header (pseudo code):

```
... Headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer ey... "
```

I have 3 stages on 3 servers (test, Dev, prod).
On test and Dev the token is recognized as valid and the endpoint returns success message.
On prod i get the following error:

> IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match 'kid': '" 4Wqj...'

When I have a look at my jwks from discovery document, I can verify the given jwk with the stated kid is existing and matching the kid in the access token.

All three servers are in the same intranet.

I have no idea what is the reason for this error only on the prod server.

Comment: How did you verify the token? You could get the three tokens and parse them with [jwt.io](https://jwt.io), and then you could check the kids of them. Or this may due to the [signing key rollover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover).

Comment: We verified the tokens with jwt.io and they seems okay and include a valid kid. `We use  app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
     new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
     {
     // ...
     });` as advised in the link you provided so roll over sholud be no problem.